# LinkedIn: Auto Login using linkedin button without pressing the button

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have created the Linkedin sign for my application and where I am in need of to do auto login using linkedin without pressing linkedin button (i.e , Automatic login using linkedin It should onloading of button).  Here I have tried the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: key comes here
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>
```

But I never get correct answer..

Comment: doesnt authorize: true work..? As per docs,  this will cause the framework to automatically fetch an OAuth token (if one is available) for signed in users ..? or did i get you wrong ...?

Comment: yes , authorize : true , doesnt work for me

Comment: can you post code for onLinkedInLoad function as well..?

Comment: The user should be already logged in at linkedin.com for this to work.

Comment: function onLinkedInLoad() {
                IN.ENV.js.scope = new Array();
                IN.ENV.js.scope[0] = "r_emailaddress";
                IN.ENV.js.scope[1] = "r_contactinfo";  
     
                //IN.User.authorize();
                IN.Event.on(IN, "", onLinkedInAuth);
            }

Comment: @samer yes , I tried that too but It also  not worked....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include  `IN.User.authorize();`

like this

```
function onLinkedInLoad() {
                IN.ENV.js.scope = new Array();
                IN.ENV.js.scope[0] = "r_emailaddress";
                IN.ENV.js.scope[1] = "r_contactinfo";  
                IN.User.authorize();
                IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
            }
```